# QPushButton background color dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qstylesheet

I have a `QPushButton` on which I would like to set the background color. I can use stylesheets for this:

```
m_iconButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                            "background-color: red "
                            "}");
```

However I want to use this in a function `void foo(const QColor& a_color)`. How would I make sure that the stylesheet takes this `a_color` as an argument?

So something like this:

```
void foo(const QColor& color) {
        m_iconButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                                    "background-color: a_color"
                                    "}");
}
```

Is there a way to do this with stylesheets? And if not, how can I do this without them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void foo(const QColor& color) {
        m_iconButton->setStyleSheet(QString("QPushButton {"
                                            "background-color: %1"
                                            "}")
                                       .arg(color.name()));
}
```